# Populating combobox with filtered contents of a store

Tags: extjs, combobox, filter, store

I am using Ext.js 4

I am trying to populate a combobox using the contents of a store after filtering.

I have one JSON object (soon to be one MySQL table) call Lists which contains an array of listId and name.  I want to populate my combobox based on the listId.

Here's my code, at the top of the definition of the combobox:

```
Ext.define('FirstApp.view.tab.Edit', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
alias : 'widget.tabedit',

title : 'Edit Worksheet',
layout: 'fit',
autoShow: true,

id: 'tab.Edit',

initComponent: function() {

    var store = Ext.getStore("Lists");
    console.log('store: ' + store);
    var listFilter = new Ext.util.Filter({ property: 'listID', value: 2 });
    console.log('listFilter: ' + listFilter);
    var list2 = store.load().filter(listFilter);
    console.log('list2: ' + list2);
```

and then later...

```
    store: list2,
```

but I get list2 is undefined as per the following console messages...

```
store: [object Object]
listFilter: [object Object]
list2: undefined
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Bill, I noticed you asked several questions but did not mark any replies as answered. Please do that otherwise people don't get their award points.

Comment: Sorry, DmitryB, but I don't see where to mark the replies as answered.  Is it just "Was this helpful"?

Comment: There is a hollow check mark next to every answer, you need to click on it to accept. Also use the up arrow next to the answer if you find it useful whether or not it is the one you select as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The filter method does not return a store but rather removes data from the store for display. So you can't set a variable with the return of that method call. 
so instead your store property should just be set to the store variable.

Comment: That worked.  Thank you.  var myList = Ext.getStore('Lists');
myList.filter({ property: 'companyId', value:  MyGlobalData.companyId });